# Setting and skipping callbacks in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a callback defined in my model as

```
 after_commit :method, on: [:create, :update]
```

In my test I want to disable this callback using `set_callback` method. How can I do it?

Comment: Just stub it out, perhaps? This way callback runs, but doesn't do anything.

Comment: What is your Rails version? What is the transactional fixtures setting? In some cases (older Rails, transactional_fixtures=true) after_commit is never run during the tests. See [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18458) for more details.

Comment: I am using Rails 4. I tried something like Company.set_callback :commit, :after, :update_redis_keys, :on => [:create, :update] but sets the callback even on destroy. I want to set the callback only on create and update

Answer (score 3):

`set_callback` is used to **add** a callback to a model:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods/set_callback

I think `skip_callback` is to be used here:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_callback

You would call it like this:

```
SomeModel.skip_callback(:commit, :after, :method)
```

It's often used in test factories, for instance to skip a `before_save` method called `some_method`:

```rb
factory :user do
  after(:build) do |user|
    user.class.skip_callback(:save, :before, :some_method)
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to undo/reset the skip_callback whenever you use in the Factory, this impacts all the classes, not just that instance.

Comment: It impacts all the instances of that class, indeed. But that's usually fine in the context of tests, you do want to disable the callbacks for all instances.

Comment: This will persist across test cases/contexts. You must undo for testing the callback behavior, for example.

Answer (score -1):

For any model named `SomeModel`, you can call the method `skip_callback` with the type of callback :

```
SomeModel.skip_callback(:after_commit)
```

Then, any operation you do on a record of SomeModel will be done without your after_commit callback.

Documentation : http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_callback

Comment: Actually this doesn't work for `after_commit` . I'm getting error: 
`NoMethodError: undefined method _after_commit_callbacks' for <Class:0x007fa81db97cc0>`

Comment: @zauzaj maybe `SomeModel.skip_callback(:after)` ?